# T-SQL Question - Counting and Average

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a set of data that consists of a filenbr, open date and close date.

I need to produce a summary table similar to the below, i need to count how many files belong to each day period, but i need those greater than 20 grouped together.  I know how to get the datediff, what i'm stumbling on is how to get the 20+ and the % column

```
1 day - 30 files - 30%
3 days - 25 files - 25%
10 days - 5 files - 5%
13 days - 20 files - 20%
>= 20 days - 20 files - 20%
```

Comment: Does "3 Days" mean that the difference between the Open and Close date is exactly 3 days, that it is at most 3 days or that it at least 3 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have a table named dayFile with the following columns

Table DayFile

```
days - files
1    - 10
1    - 5
1    - 15
3    - 20
3    - 5
10   - 5
13   - 20
20   - 5
22   - 5
28   - 10
```

Then you could do the following

```
SELECT
    SummaryTable.Day,
    SUM(SummaryTable.Files) as SumFiles,
    Sum(SummaryTable.Files) / SummaryTable.TotalFiles
  FROM 
    (SELECT 
      CASE WHEN (days >= 20) THEN
        20
      ELSE DF.days END as Day
      files,
      (SELECT Count(*) FROM DayFile DFCount) as TotalFiles
    FROM DayFile DF) SummaryTable
Group By SummaryTable.Day
```

---

**EDITED:**

```
SELECT
    SummaryTable.Day,
    SUM(SummaryTable.Files) as SumFiles,
    Sum(SummaryTable.Files) / (SELECT Count(*) FROM DayFile DFCount)
FROM 
    (SELECT 
      CASE WHEN (days >= 20) THEN
        20
      ELSE DF.days END as Day
      files
    FROM DayFile DF) SummaryTable
Group By SummaryTable.Day
```

Comment: Very helpful, only thing I'm running into now is:

'Column 'SummaryTable.TotalFiles' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: sorry about that.  Check the second query.

Answer (score 0):

You are unclear as to how the ranges are determined (e.g. does "3 days mean < 3 days, <= 3 days, = 3 days, > 3 days or >= 3 days?). If you are using SQL Server 2005 and higher, you get your results like so:

```
With PeriodLength As
    (
    Select DateDiff(d, OpenDate, CloseDate) As DiffDays
    From Table
    )
    , Ranges As 
    (
    Select Case
            When DiffDays < 3 Then 'Less than 3 Days'
            When DiffDays >= 3 And DiffDays < 10 Then 'Less than 10 Days'
            When DiffDays >= 10 And DiffDays < 13 Then 'Less than 13 Days'
            When DiffDays >= 13 And DiffDays < 20 Then 'Less than 20 Days'
            When DiffDays >= 20 Then 'Greater than 20 days'
            End As Range
    From PeriodLength   
    )
Select Range
    , Count(*) As FileCount
    , Count(*) * 100.000 / (Select Count(*) From Ranges) As Percentage
From Ranges 
Group By Range
```

Comment: You could also use BETWEEN here to easier show the ranges. < 3 is ok, then between to segment the other ranges, then an ELSE to catch-all the others (Which are then > your highest range)

Comment: @cairnz - I'm not a huge fan of the Between keyword because it does not express what will happen as clearly as using `>` and `>=`. If I write `Between 10 and 20`, the reader has to know that this includes the end points. Whereas if I write, `Foo >= 10 And Foo <= 20` it is clear whether I'm including the end points.